# Controlling use and packages of two different Python installations ("regular" and "anaconda")

Tags: python, numpy, import, anaconda, failed-installation

I have two installations of python on a windows 7 machine. One regular (C:\Python27\python.exe) and one with Anaconda (C:\Anaconda\python.exe).

My problem is:

1) when I  open "C:\Python27\python.exe" I get the following error message:`"ImportError: No module named numpy"`
, even though the numpy folder is located under "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages"

2) when I try to install numpy in the regular command window (C:\Python27\python.exe) using "pip install numpy" I get the following message:
`"Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages"`

3) I need to keep the regular python package (C:\Python27\python.exe) since I have a third program which uses this python-installation.

Does anybody know how can I install numpy properly here? And; is there any way to say which version of python I want to use when using the command window?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which is your "default app"  .py file(s) ?
Check system environments (path).

Comment: The variable named PATH for my user account is "C:\Users\vibeke.browne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda;C:\Users\vibeke.browne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Scripts"

Comment: Friend, installed in anaconda and call from idle, copy numpy form "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages" to "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages". Or read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path i hope helpful